# Operators in derived class redefining but still using parent class

Tags: c++, operators, derived-class, ostream

Specifically, I would like to be able to use the `ostream` `operator <<` in two derived classes from a base class.

The program I am creating is supposed to print out product details for various "products" in a "virtual store". Among the products are two different kinds of books. Each of these books is supposed to hold their own:

```
ID number
Author
NumberOfPages
Year
```

In addition, type `ChildrensBook` needs to hold a minimum age, and `TextBook` needs to hold a grade.

I defined class `Book` and derived from it classes `ChildrensBook` and `TextBook`. My question is about using the `ostream` `operator <<` to print out the information.

Can I define a generic << function in the Book class, which will print out all of the information common to both derived classes, and then refer to it in the redefinition of << in the derived classes?

For example,

```
//The parent class

ostream& operator<<(ostream& bookOutput, const Book& printBook) {
    return bookOutput << printBook.ID << "Name " << printBook.name << "year:" << printBook.year";
}
```

And then in the derived class somehow:

```
//The derived classes
ostream& operator<<(ostream& TextBookOutput, const TextBook& printTextBook) {
    return TextBookOutput << "TextBook: " 
           << "[Here is where I want to print out all the details of the book that are members of the base class]" << "Grade:" << printTextBook.grade;
}
```

So I guess my question can be summed up as: Can I call the parent operator from within the child operator, and if so, what syntax do I use?

Another idea that occurred to me is to write a function for the child that uses the parent print operator, and then call that function from within the child's print operator.  That would mean that I wasn't trying to call an operator while redefining it, but still calls for using the parent operator and separately redefining the child operator.

Comment: Are you sure this is what you want? If you try to stream a  reference to the base class (`Book&`) that refers to a derived class (`TextBook&` or `ChildrensBook&`) you won't call the specialised operators, just the base class version.

Answer (score 4):

Sure.

You have an operator for `Book`s, so use it. You can invoke it by giving it a reference to a book, and you can use the power of polymorphism to obtain a reference-to-base.

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& TextBookOutput, const TextBook& printTextBook) {
    return TextBookOutput << "TextBook: " << static_cast<const Book&>(printTextBook) << "Grade:" << printTextBook.grade;
}
```

Comment: And before you all start, yes this _is_ polymorphism. Downcasts are a special case of polymorphism that require `virtual`, but upcasting through a reference is polymorphism too.

Comment: @unapersson: Why would it not?

Comment: @unapersson: How do you expect the proper operator to be called otherwise?

Comment: @unapersson: You appear to be suggesting [this](http://codepad.org/7JXqSrSp). I am suggesting [this](http://codepad.org/ThZn9HtQ).

Comment: @unapersson: Argh! I _hate_ when people delete comments! Leave them on so that others may learn from your mistake, and our subsequent discourse.

Comment: Thanks a ton, this is perfect!  plus getting me to understand static_cast, which I hadn't quite gotten ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
return TextBookOutput << static_cast<Book const &>(printTextBook) << ...
```

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out, you should use downcasting to achieve what you are asking for. But I think you should consider a different approach as well: What you are doing right now is mixing *static* and *dynamic* polymorphism, this often isn't a good idea (which usually only manifests itself later on).

Here is the problem, consider what you've got already:
`class Book { ... };
class TextBook : public Book { ... };
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Book& book) {
    return os << "Book: " << book.name << "\n";
}
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const TextBook& book) {
    return os << "TextBook: " << book.name << "\n";
}`

Everything will go as expected if you use it like this:

`Book book;
TextBook textBook;
cout << book << "\n";     // prints out: Book: XYZ
cout << textBook << "\n"; // prints out: TextBook: XYZ` 

That is because the compiler will correctly determine the type of the book during compilation time (statically).

Now consider this other case:
`Book * textBook = new TextBook();
cout << *textBook << "\n";    // prints out: Book: XYZ !`

This is because the compiler can't know what higher type it is, it can be Book, TextBook or ChildrensBook. This can only be determined during runtime (dynamically) using virtual functions etc.

So in case you consider utilizing dynamic polymorphism I would prefer this approach:

`class Book {
  public:
  virtual ostream& print(ostream& os) const { return os << "Book: XYZ"; }
  // Don't forget virtual destructor.
  virtual ~Book() {}
};
class TextBook : public Book {
  public:
  virtual ostream& print(ostream& os) const
  {
    // Here, you can also call the "print" method of the parent class
    // like this: os << Book::print(os);
    // or just invent your own like this:
    return os << "TextBook: XYZ";
  }
};
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Book& book) {
  // Will correctly decide during runtime whether
  // to use Book::print or TextBook::print.
  return book.print(os);
}`